# Beginner: JButton/Gridlayout (Similar to Minesweeper)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout, minesweeper

I am a beginner with Java and eventually I would like to create code for a robot I am making for a senior project. I am planning for the robot to set up dominoes in a specified pattern to then be knocked down. I first need to write a program that will allow me to choose dominoes to be placed on a grid. I am then planning on having the program print out a new program for Arduino.

As a test and to learn, I would like to make a 20x40 grid with JButtons. I would then like to click a few Jbuttons then add the Jbutton values to a new array. ex. I click the 1st, 5th, 30th, and 799th button. The program will then add those to a new array where `array[0]=1`, `array[2]=5;` etc.

I spent many hours with trial and error and looking online to come up with this code:
The problem right now is that it seems to be skipping the Buttongrid method (?). If I make the method public static void main (String [] args){, then the action listener doesn't work.

Again, I am JUST beginning so I will not be surprised if many things are wrong.
Please just take a look at it and help me figure out what I have to fix.
Thanks

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ButtonGrid extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
static int clicked[]=new int[800];  
static JButton button[]=new JButton[800];
static int x;
static int count=0;
int value;
ActionListener listen;
    public  ButtonGrid() { 
        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        GridLayout grid=new GridLayout(20,40);
        frame.setLayout(grid);
    //fill clicked with 0s////////////////////////////////////
            for (int c=0;c<=10;c++){
        clicked[c]=0;}
            for(x=0;x<800;x++){  
           button[x]= new JButton();
           button[x].setActionCommand(Integer.toString(x));
           frame.add(button[x]);
           button[x].addActionListener(this);
            }}
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


            while(count<11){
                int newvalue=value;
                 value=Integer.parseInt( e.getActionCommand());  
                 if(value!=newvalue){
                    clicked[count]=this.value;
                    count=count+1;
                    System.out.println("Found");
                 }
                 else{
                     newvalue=value;
                     System.out.println("Looking...");}}
            }   public static void main(String [] args){
                        ButtonGrid b=new ButtonGrid();
                        if (count>10){
                        for (int t=0;t<=11;t++){
                            System.out.println(clicked[t]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
```

Comment: Is your actual source code formatted like that?  That would give me a headache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't call your ButtonGrid  frame in main class , Like this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("this prints and no window pops up. it skipped       the grid/frame code");
        ButtonGrid b = new ButtonGrid();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it. I really appreciate it. My new problem is the structure of the while loop that adds the first 10 clicked button values to the int array clicked[] which then gets printed. The loop gets stuck in the else/listening... area and never gives me a chance to click another button. I updated the code above.

Comment: i don't know what you want to do in your while loop , but clearly that your code will loop forever , because :1-`int newvalue = value;` 2-  `if (value != newvalue)` which will be `false` forever  from equation `1`  so it will never execute and will go to the `else` statement `newvalue = value;`  in which you didn't change the `count`  so it will be = `0`

Comment: this is where you stuck in , so tell me exactly the algorithm which you want to use it :)

Comment: Here is what I wanted to happen. First the value becomes newvalue so the loop repeats. Then I thought if I pressed a button, value would suddenly become, say 32. then value would not equal newvalue and the value would be added to the array clicked[0] because count =0. then count becomes 1. If I press another button within the loop. say 330, then clicked[1]=330 because count =1 and value=330.  if i dont press anything after, value = newvalue so it would skip. I now see the loop is so fast, and I would have to click the button in between the 1st and 3rd lines to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: so you need to make this loop inside `Thread` , thread will allows you to change the value , because inside the loop the value will never change.